# WCFDataService Returning Boolean

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

I am trying task using WCFDataServices.

I have a Service operation Like

[WebInvoke(Method="POST")]

Public bool Add(string x1, string x2, string x3)

{

// ADDS a NEW RECORD TO DB. AND IF THE ADDITION IS SUCCESSFULL RETURs true or false

}

In my MVC Client Application. In the repository I have Function to Add Like

public bool Add(string y1, string y2, string y3)

{

// HERE I WANT to EXECUTE THE URI AND CAPUTURE THE RETURNED VALUE. AND PASS IT TO MY CONTROLLER TO SHOW SOME ACTION IN THE VIEW.

}

I dont have any problem in the service. It returns the boolean value as expected.

I couldnt figure out how i can capture the returned boolean value in my Repository Method.

// OperationResponse x = dsContext.Execute(requestUri,  Microsoft.Data.OData.HttpMethod.Post);

I tried to do something like above line.But didnt work.

Thanks For Your Time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using WCF Data Services 5.0 on the client (since you're using the Execute with a method). Please upgrade to the RTM bits (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2012/04/09/wcf-data-services-5-0-rtm-release.aspx), which are also available on NuGet (search for Microsoft.Data.Services.Client). After that this code should work just fine:

```
public bool Add(string x1, string x2, string x3)
{
     return this.ctx.Execute<bool>(
         new Uri("Add", UriKind.Relative),
         "POST",
         /*singleResult*/ true,
         new UriOperationParameter("x1", x1),
         new UriOperationParameter("x2", x2),
         new UriOperationParameter("x3", x3))
         .Single();
}
```